# Getting Facebook groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

My project is to get around 1000 Facebook groups and do some analysis of the data collected from those groups. Is there any way to accumulate Facebook group ID's (1000 or less) so that I don't have to manually search for each Facebook group. Is there a query or something that allows me to see Facebook groups based on category, etc?

Comment: Facebook doesn't want applications (or users) to be able to mine data in such a way that you are describing... You might have better luck targeting specific users and testing what groups *they* are in.

Comment: I already did some analysis on 100 Facebook groups, but I had to get each Facebook group ID separately which is requiring huge amounts of time, I was just wondering if there is a way to get that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question correctly, but facebook has a very convenient api for this:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=programming&type=group&access_token=lala

It is on the developer page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
Batch requests in Graph API to get more ids at once 
see https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/03/17/batch-requests-in-graph-api/